# Reuse specific areas

Tags: sharepoint-designer, reusable

I am new to Sharepoint and I am in search for a solution of a problem I have right now. I have multiple pages, each with a sidebar menu. The menu is different throughout the pages of the website but there could be a set of pages that have the same menu (not the menu of the website).

Is there any solution to have this menu in a reusable place? And also to have the ability to edit it easily.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint use the ASP.NET concept of the Master page. This will locate the common content used throughout a page. You can go to Add Item and select Master Page in SP Designer. Another option is creating a separate webpart for it. Then locate the webpart inside each page. Pass a parameter through URL and customize the content.